# Sencha Touch - Listeners and Event Delegation - will they blend?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I've recently started using Sencha Touch on a project, although I've used ExtJS for some time the two are different in many ways. To complicate the learning curve, I'm applying ST as more of an underlying framework than as a whole UI/framework/does everything deal. As such, I've come across a situation where I'd like to use the array method of setting listeners for elements while also wanting to maintain the use of events such as "painted" and such.

Here's an example - I'm 99% positive there is a better way to do what I'm trying to do:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    html: '<ul><li id="blah">Blah</li><li id="hooey">Hooey</li></ul>',
    listeners: [{
        element: 'element',
        delegate: 'li#blah',
        event: 'tap',
        fn: function() { /* do something for blah */ }
    },{ 
        /* repeat for hooey, etc */
    }]
});
```

On the flip side, what if I want a standard listener on the container?

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    listeners: {
        activate: function() {
            // do some stuff here
        }
    }
 });
```

I'd like to know the Best Practice for doing these on the same component instead of, say, having to do the activate listener and then apply the element tap event handlers to the component on activate/show/paint/whathaveyou.

Note: tagging with extjs as I **assume** it applies there as well - if not, please feel free to edit or let me know and I'll pull the tag.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to ask. Are you confused about setting DOM event listeners vs. Component event listeners? It would help if you provided concrete examples...

Comment: Well, I was curious about how, if possible, you would set both element and component listeners in the same config. Also, I haven't seen any good documentation on element event listeners in the API docs (though I def could've missed it). The only method I'm aware of for element listeners is the one presented in my first example.

Comment: See my answer. Is this what you were asking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you shouldn't mess with Component's Elements from another Component, imagine that they are like private properties (Component's render html can change so don't rely on it), the code in your first example doesn't look good, I didn't even know this can work at all. You should implement Component events for exporting to the ouside world.

In some specific cases you can export your elements via methods like getEl(), getScrollerEl(), etc. But most of the time it's an indication that you're doing something wrong.

P.S. Binding element event listeners is described in [Ext.dom.Element](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Observable-method-addListener) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks - I think the way I am (or was) doing things wasn't the best way for sure, but on a tight schedule and working with a prepared layout ... I did what I could. I was hoping to make it a little easier to add both element and component listeners at the same time, since a component may have had a contentEl with parts that needed events (and no time to dive into styling Touch's components), but also would have needed component events like painted or show.  Thanks though